# Write two lists to two different columns in a csv file in python

Tags: python, list, csv

How would you go about writing two different lists to two columns in a csv file without it splitting words into characters? Trying to create one column for "title" and another for "score".

```
with open("file.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
writer.writerow(('Title', 'Score'))
for i in zip(list1, list2):
    writer.writerow(i)
```

This returns

Title   Score

T   S

i   c

t   o

l   r

e   e

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to iterate through the zipped arrays. You do need to replace your delimiter, though.

```
with open("file.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(('Title', 'Score'))
    writer.writerows(zip(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually your code works completely fine. A complete example:

```py
import csv

list1 = ['one','two']
list2 = ['three','four']

with open("file.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(('Title', 'Score'))
    for i in zip(list1, list2):
        writer.writerow(i)
```

results in

```
Title   Score
one three
two four
```

So the information missing from your question is what list1 and list2 actually are, if list1 is just the string 'Title' and list2 is just the string 'Score' then you would get your result, because it iterates over the characters (as they are just strings, not lists).